# Run loop in `std::future` until destruction - idiomatic way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, future

I want a member `std::future<void>` to continuously call a function inside a loop until the parent object is destroyed.

My current solution involves wrapping the future in a class with a boolean flag and setting the flag to false on destruction.

```
class Wrapper
{
    std::future<void> fut;
    bool wrapperAlive{true};

public:
    Wrapper() : fut{std::async(std::launch::async, [this]
    { 
        while(wrapperAlive) doSomething();
    })} { }

    ~Wrapper()
    {
        wrapperAlive = false;
    }
};
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Without knowing the actual problem you try to solve, this looks like more a job for a `std::thread` instead. `std::async` and `std::future` are more for short processing that returns a value, not for longer threads of work that doesn't return anything. It doesn't really change your question though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I'm just using `std::future<void>` to automatically join the thread on destruction. As far as I know `~std::thread()` does not call join.

Comment: This code probably has a data race on `wrapperAlive`. You need some form of synchronization.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Hurb Sutter has a great [talk on concurency](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism) where he does almost this.  It is at 54:30 into the presentation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: the thing is that the join will only return *after* you set the boolean, at which point you have already raced.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, OP has seen my comment and has fixed their code. I think the comment no longer serves a purpose, so I'll delete it.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The "almost" is key, there is a distinct difference: he changes the bool from the running thread, not from the destructor itself.

Comment: @Yexo That is why I said almost.  My comment was more just to show the OP the video as it is a good talk IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a data-race free version of your code:

```
class Wrapper {
  std::atomic<bool> wrapperAlive{true}; // construct flag first!
  std::future<void> fut;
public:
  Wrapper() :
    fut{std::async(std::launch::async, [this]
      { 
        while(wrapperAlive)
          doSomething();
      }
    )}
  {}

  ~Wrapper() {
    wrapperAlive = false;
    fut.get(); // block, so it sees wrapperAlive before it is destroyed.
  }
};
```

the next thing I'd do is write:

```
template<class F>
struct repeat_async_t {
  F f;
  // ...
};
using repeat_async = repeat_async_t<std::function<void()>>;
template<class F>
repeat_async_t<std::decay_t<F>> make_repeat_async(F&&f){
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

which takes a task to repeat forever, and bundle it up in there, rather than mixing the flow logic with what is executed logic.

At this point, we will probably want to add in an abort method.

Finally, it is very rarely a good idea to busy-loop a thread.  So we'd add in some kind of wait-for-more-data-to-consume system.

And it ends up looking a lot different than your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently using this kind of busy loop with sockets and thread-safe queues: I have a thread-safe receive queue with a busy loop that tries to receive packets from an UDP socket and enqueue them. I also have a busy loop that dequeues packets and processes them. What is the correct way of doing this kind of packet enqueue-ing/processing without similar busy loops?

Comment: @Jamboree: Yes, but I wanted to implement a simple server/client architecture for learning experience

Comment: @Yakk: Why is `fut.get();` necessary in `~Wrapper()`? Shouldn't it be automatically called in `std::future`'s destructor, which is called right after `~Wrapper()`?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I can see a possible issue: currently std::future's destructor does block, however, this could change in the future, which would break your code at that point if get() wasn't explicitly called.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo It isn't strickly required.  For a bit I thought there was a dependency problem with the atomic.  However, in MSVC2013 std::future's destructor does not block (they violated the standard).  A side benefit is that if you change the implementation of the constructor to build the future some other way, this will still block (only async generated futures block in dtor).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo For your first question, network and similar io interfaces usually have a "wake me up when the next packet arrives" interface.  Ideally the consume code would only busy loop for a shrot period of time waiting for new packets, and if no packet arrives in 0.1 second would wait on a signal rather than burn CPU pointlessly.  This requires that the "abort" signal from the object dtor also get through, which can be done by using platform-specific tools, or doing a slow busy-loop of some kind with async shutdown.